# how to make this group filter script only for active users

Tags: powershell

I was wondering if this script could be changed into one for only active users?

```
import-module ActiveDirectory
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\test\teetest.txt"
$groups = Get-ADGroup -filter {(name -like "runners*") -or (name -like "helpers*")
foreach($group in $groups)
{
    $countUser = (Get-ADGroupMember $group.DistinguishedName).count
    Write-Host "The group $($group.Name) has $countUser user(s)."
}
Stop-Transcript
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by active users?

Comment: enabled users to be exact

Comment: with all the reccomendations i keep getting the output 6 or 0 on all groups while all groups have different amounts of users

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly and by active users you mean groups with at least 1 member(i.e. greater than 0). You could just filter out results using `Where-Object` cmdlet. Like so:

```
$groups = Get-ADGroup -filter {(name -like "runners*") -or (name -like "helpers*") -Properties Members | Where-Object { $_.Members.Count –gt 0 }
```

Comment: sorry it is where the users are enabled. not where the count is greater then 0

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a filter to only get the number of active Members in the Group.

Since `Get-ADGroupMember` doesn't supply all properties for the Users you have to do another lookup for each of them:

```
$countUser = (Get-ADGroupMember $group.DistinguishedName | % { Get-ADuser -Identity $_ -Property Enabled | Where-Object {$_.Enabled -eq $true}}).count
```

**Explanation:**

`% { Get-ADuser -Identity $_ -Property Enabled` - Get the Informations for each User found in the Group with the Enabled Property added to it

`Where-Object {$_.Enabled -eq $true}` - Filters the users that are enabled

Comment: when i do this it tells me all the groups have 0 users ever though they don't do you know why?

Comment: the output keeps being 0 can you share the complete script that worked?

Comment: my script now looks like this  import-module activedirectory

Start-Transcript -Path "C:\test\teetest.txt"

$groups = Get-ADGroup -filter { (name -like "runners*") -or (name -like "helpers*")

foreach($group in $groups) {

    $countUser = (Get-ADGroupMember $group.DistinguishedName | % { Get-ADuser -Identity $_ -Property Enabled | Where-Object {$_.Enabled -eq $true}}).count

    Write-Host "The group $($group.Name) has $countUser user(s)."

}

Stop-Transcript

Comment: the error i am getting is this Get-ADGroup : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '​'.
At C:\test\vergelijkenscript.ps1:5 char:11
+ $groups = Get-ADGroup -filter { (name -like "runners*") -or (name -like "helpers...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADGroup], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup

Comment: Like I said, `$groups = Get-ADGroup -filter { (name -like "runners*") -or (name -like "helpers*")´ should be `$groups = Get-ADGroup -filter { (name -like "runners*") -or (name -like "helpers*")}` instead. You are missing an `}`.

Comment: i changed it but it still says that there are 0 users :(. i dont know what i am doing wrong here then

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be because the `Get-ADGroupMember` not just returns user objects with a limited set of properties, but can also return groups and computers.

Since you are only looking for users that are direct descendents of the groups 'runners*' or 'helpers*', it is better to limit the objects returned by the `Get-ADGroupMember` cmdlet to be **users** only.
Below I do this by adding  `Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq "user" }`.
Next, to ensure the `.Count` property can be used I would suggest to enclose the thing in a `@()` so the returned value actually is an array and therefore has the `Count` property.

For a script like this, I also suggest NOT to try and put it all in one single line, because that makes spotting mistakes (like forgetting a closing bracket) more difficult.

Try this:

```
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\test\teetest.txt" 
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {(name -like "runners*") -or (name -like "helpers*")}
foreach($group in $groups) { 
    $countUser = 0
    Get-ADGroupMember $group.DistinguishedName | Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq "user" } |
    ForEach-Object { 
        if ((Get-ADuser -Identity $_.DistinguishedName).Enabled) { $countUser++ }
    }

    Write-Host "The group $($group.Name) has $countUser user(s)." 
}
Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: when i try your version some of this script some of the groups have 1 users and some of them have 0. There are more users in each of these groups. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Ah, yes.. Totally wrong the first time. I have edited the code

Answer (score -1):

Replace the $countUser statement alone with below example.

For only Enabled User Accounts

```
$countUserEnabled = (get-aduser -filter *|where {$_.enabled -eq "True"}).count
```

For only Disabled User Accounts

```
$countUserDisabled = (get-aduser -filter *|where {$_.enabled -ne "False"}).count
```

Comment: i tried this and the output is now telling me that each group has six users? Is this a bug                                                                                                                   import-module activedirectory

Start-Transcript -Path "C:\test\teetest.txt"

$groups = Get-ADGroup -filter {(name -like "allissar*") -or (name -like "birmingham flowers*")}​

foreach($group in $groups) {

    $countUserEnabled = (get-aduser -filter *|where {$_.enabled -eq "True"}).count

    Write-Host "The group $($group.Name) has $countUserEnabled user(s)."

}

Stop-Transcript

Comment: @sjoerdomans `(get-aduser -filter *|where {$_.enabled -eq "True"}).count` gives you the number of all enabled users in your AD.